# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' for echo statement with variables

Tags: php

I have a php file where it has a table with check box with the value which is equal to the ID from MYSQL table. When I run it I get the error. 
I know there is some problem with " and ' can any one help in solving this?

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    ***//I get error in the following line*** 
    echo"<td> <form action="del_prod.php" method="post">input type="checkbox" name="product_id" value="$row["product_id"]"></td>"
    echo "<td>" . $row['product_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td >" . $row['product_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['weight'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Please read [PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) I am sure you can correct it by yourself.

Comment: But what is the meaning of using `form` in line ` echo"<td> <form action="del_prod.php" method="post">input type="checkbox" name="product_id" value="$row["product_id"]"></td>"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several problems with your line.

```
echo "<td><form action=\"del_prod.php\" method=\"post\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"product_id\" value=\"".$row['product_id']."\" /></td>";
```

- You're not escaping the double quotes.
- You are missing the opening < on the input tag.
- You're not closing the input tag.
- You're not concatenating the $row['product_id'] in the string properly.
- You're missing a semi-colon.

This is all aside from the fact that the form tag shouldn't really be in the `<td>`. It should be outside of the table, or better yet without a table at all! :)

Comment: `form` tag open but not closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo"<td><form action='del_prod.php' method='post'><input type='checkbox' name='product_id' value='".$row['product_id']."'></td>";
```

Comment: Add a semicolumn after your statement.

Answer (score 0):

Change -

```
echo"<td> <form action="del_prod.php" method="post">input type="checkbox" name="product_id" value="$row["product_id"]"></td>";
```

To

```
echo'<td> <form action="del_prod.php" method="post">input type="checkbox" name="product_id" value="$row["product_id"]"></td>';
```

your quotes are `conflicting` and missing `;` at the end

Answer (score 0):

you missed `;` in this line, also escape the `"` double quotes.

```
echo"<td> <form action=\"del_prod.php\" method=\"post\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"product_id\" value=\"$row[\"product_id\"]\"></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the quotation marks and you're missing a semi column, you can correct this like so

```
echo"<td> <form action=\"del_prod.php\" method=\"post\">input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"product_id\" value=".$row["product_id"]."></td>";
```

Alternatively, you can use single quotation marks to make life a bit easier.

This link may help: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to escape the `"` in your statement like this:

```
echo'<td> <form action="del_prod.php" method="post">input type="checkbox" name="product_id" value="' . $row["product_id"] . '"></td>';
```

Comment: Posted to quick, thx @swapnesh !

Comment: its good to be more specific than being fast :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
echo"<td> <form action="del_prod.php" method="post">input type="checkbox" name="product_id" value="$row["product_id"]"></td>"
```

TO

```
echo"<td> <form action='del_prod.php' method='post'>input type='checkbox' name='product_id' value='$row['product_id']'></td>"
```

You can use single quotation mark in your echo strong.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be written as

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    //I get error in the following line*** 
    echo "<td> 
        <form action='del_prod.php' method='post'>
            <input type='checkbox' name='product_id' value='".$row["product_id"]."'/>
        </form>
    </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['product_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td >" . $row['product_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['weight'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    //***//I get error in the following line*** 
    echo"<td> <form action=\"del_prod.php\" method=\"post\">input type=\"checkbox\ name=\"product_id\" value=\"$row['product_id']\"></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['product_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td >" . $row['product_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['weight'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```